# How to detect when collapsible button is clicked in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am wondering if there is some API to detect when the collapsible item is opened in jQuery mobile.

https://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/

or we have to use custom jQuery events?

I mean there is a method to detect the expanding of the collapsible set

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "collapsibleexpand", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

but no API way to detect which of the item has been expanded...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the not collapsed div:

```
$('#myc').on('collapsibleexpand', function( event, ui ) {
    $(this).find('div.ui-collapsible:not(.ui-collapsible-collapsed)')...
});
```

or attach an event handler:

```
$('a.ui-collapsible-heading-toggle').on('tap click', function(e) {
    ....
})
```

The snippet:

```js
$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
    $('a.ui-collapsible-heading-toggle').on('tap click', function(e) {
        if ($(this).closest('div.ui-collapsible').is('.ui-collapsible-collapsed')) {
            console.log('tap click: ' + this.childNodes[0].textContent);
        }
    })

    $('#myc').on('collapsibleexpand', function( event, ui ) {
        var ele = $(this).find('div.ui-collapsible:not(.ui-collapsible-collapsed)');
        console.log('collapsibleexpand: ' + ele.find('a.ui-collapsible-heading-toggle').get(0).childNodes[0].textContent);
    });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>


<div data-role="content" id="myc">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>I'm a header1</h3>
        <p>I'm the collapsible content. By default I'm closed, but you can click the header to open me.</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>I'm a header2</h3>
        <p>I'm the collapsible content. By default I'm closed, but you can click the header to open me.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Actually I would like to get access to the content of this expanded item. Would you mind to detalize your solution please.

Comment: When attaching listeners in jQM, it should be wrapped in `pagecreate` not `.ready`.

Comment: @Omar Would you mind to help me to get access to the content of a div of the collapsible item please?

Comment: @Dimi you can access content from within the event. `$(this)` is the object with all content do the collapsible which fired the event. E.g. `$(this).find( ".foo" ).addClass( "bar" );`.